# Upload and download byte value not same

Tags: android, upload, download

I am using the following code to upload sql file and then download it. Though all the data is restored from the data file but the byte value written and read are not same. I want them to be same as I will be encrypting/decryping data later and it will not work correctly on different data.

Upload details:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

         dialog.dismiss(); 

         Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                             +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

         return 0;

    }
    else
    {
         try { 

               // open a URL connection to the Servlet
             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
             URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

             // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
             conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
             conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
             conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
             conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

             dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                       + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

             // create a buffer of  maximum size
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

             // read file and write it into form...
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

             while (bytesRead > 0) {

               //POINT A    
               dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

              }

             // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

             // Responses from the server (code and message)
             serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
             String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

             Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                     + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

             if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {

                           Toast.makeText(BackupTest.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });                
             }    

             //close the streams //
             fileInputStream.close();
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();  
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(BackupTest.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();  
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(BackupTest.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                             + e.getMessage(), e);  
        }
        dialog.dismiss();       
        return serverResponseCode; 

     } // End else block 
   }
```

Download details:

```
public void downloadFileFromServer(String filename, String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;

    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        bytesAvailable = in.available(); 

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) != -1)
        {


            //POINT B
            fout.write(data, 0, count);

        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (in != null)
                in.close();
        if (fout != null)
                fout.close();
    }

}
```

So the value of 'buffer' at POINT A in uploadFile() and value of 'data' at POINT B in downloadFileFromServer() are not same.

Sample values:

buffer=[B@41df59c8

data=[B@41e1a310

Thanks

Comment: The "sample values" you have posted are the Strings returned by the Object class's toString() method for a Byte array, not the contents of the array.  To see the contents of the array use the Arrays class's toString() method to create a printable String.  What values in the data that was sent and received are different?

Comment: ok, i checked the values using Arrays class toString(), the difference is that the received array seem to have two extra zeros and ']' at the end 
0,0]
This is not there in the sent value. Any idea how to make them same?

Comment: Is the ] at the end from the Arrays class's toString() method?  Did you look at the file that was saved on the server by the servlet?  Was it OK?  Can there be problems with the code on the server?  Are there two programs on the server that need to be tested: one that reads and saves the file on the server and one that reads the saved file and sends it to your download code?